# What exception is thrown when key is not found in Python dictionary?

Tags: python, exception, dictionary

If I have:

```
map = { 'stack':'overflow' }

try:
  map['experts-exchange']
except:                       <--- What is the Exception type that's thrown here?
  print( 'is not free' )
```

Couldn't find it on the web. =(

Comment: Where did you look? The page at http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html says "d[key] --
Return the item of d with key key. Raises a KeyError if key is not in the map."

Comment: I basically typed "Python dictionary exception" into Bing and gave up after the first 3 links. Thought I could get a faster answer on SO. =p But thank you for including the reference link here.

Comment: You should use the interactive console to view results like this.

Comment: I think the question isn't too bad because when someone searches for it, it will show up on the search engine instead of having to search for it, right?

Comment: It's kind of ironic because this is the top Google result if you search for what Python throws if you look for a nonexistent key... Thank you ShaChris23

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
KeyError
```

if you do it on the console without the try block will tell it to you

```
>>> a = {}
>>> a['invalid']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'invalid'
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it on the console before posting, but I didn't know the "KeyError" was the actual Exception type! Noob-ness. Lol.

Comment: Chose your answer because your console suggestion made me realize KeyError was the Exception name.

Answer (score 11):

`KeyError`.

```
>>> x = {'try': 1, 'it': 2}
>>> x['wow']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    x['wow']
KeyError: 'wow'
```

Answer (score 5):

Its called **KeyError**

```
>>d={1:2}

>>d[2]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
KeyError: 2
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know the specific exception to handle, you can simply do this kind of thing,

```
map = {'stack': 'overflow'}

try:
    map['experts-exchange']
except Exception as inst:
    print(type(inst))       # the exception instance
    print(inst.args)        # arguments stored in .args
    print(inst)             # __str__ allows args to be printed directly,
                            # but may be overridden in exception subclasses
```

The out put of the above code is,

```
<class 'KeyError'>
('experts-exchange',)
'experts-exchange'
```

When an exception occurs, it may have an associated value, also known as the exception’s argument. The presence and type of the argument depend on the exception type.

The except clause may specify a variable after the exception name. The variable is bound to an exception instance with the arguments stored in instance.args. For convenience, the exception instance defines [__str __()](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) so the arguments can be printed directly without having to reference .args. One may also instantiate an exception first before raising it and add any attributes to it as desired.

Answer (score 3):

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 16:22:56) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> map = { 'a' : 'b' }
>>> print map['c']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'c'
>>>
```

So a wild guess might be...a `KeyError` ?